# SSRS can't use "Required Attendees" in dataset?

Tags: sql, xml, reporting-services, crm, fetch

I am creating report in SSRS for CRM. I have a table with Dataset for Appointment info and I noticed that it does not allow me to report on required attendees??? Is this true? If so is there a workaround around this? I basically want my report to show appointments details **and** of course who participated.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Below is the fetchXML I gathered from using Advanced Find in CRM 2013.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">




<entity name="appointment">


<attribute name="subject"/>

<attribute name="statecode"/>

<attribute name="scheduledstart"/>

<attribute name="activityid"/>

<attribute name="instancetypecode"/>

**<attribute name="requiredattendees"/>**

<order attribute="subject" descending="false"/>



<link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="regardingobjectid" alias="ae">




<filter type="and">


<condition attribute="accountid" operator="eq" value="@name"/>

</filter>

</link-entity>

</entity>

</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this information you will have to create another one datasource and retrieve information from ActivityParty entity. All items like requiredattendees, optionalattendees in appointment, from, to, cc, bcc in email, e.t.c. are stored inside ActivityParty entity.

Comment: Hi Andrii, does that mean I have to have a different table for this dataset? I wanted to include everything in one table

Comment: That means that you would not be able to include everything in one table and yes, Appointments and Attendees are stored in separated tables.

Comment: How would this look from report standpoint? So I pull appointments from my account.. it's one row per appointment.. in one of the columns is "Required Attendees". I user one data set for this.. Now you say I need to have 2 datasets.. but I can't apply 2datasets in one table. I guess it is hard to explain without uploading picture but I am just confused how would this work....

Comment: if I have 2 tables then 1) appointment 2) for Required attendees then for 2nd table.. would required attendees be in 1 cell? and how would I link it to individual appointments.. I know its a lot of questions but is there any reference on this for me to look at more?? thanks so much!

Comment: I'm not sure how YOU will do that but this is YOUR problem how to solve it. I just tried to explain how CRM DB is structured and how you can retrieve attendees. In case I will have such kind of task to put all attendees in one field I will use subreport for attendees cell or something similar to following post - [http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/creating-a-master-detail-report-in-ssrs-without-using-sub-report/](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/creating-a-master-detail-report-in-ssrs-without-using-sub-report/).